# writing delimited text as a string to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a short script where i'm trying to grab data from a URL and write it to a sheet of an existing spreadsheet. the script is as follows:

```
function urlDataImport() {
  var input = "https://reports.acc-q-data.com/clientreports/ecaldwell_201206192722/ecaldwell_20122722.txt";
  // The code below gets the HTML code.
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(input);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(data);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ptSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("pt");
  ptSheet.getActiveRange().setValues(data);
}
```

the information in **data** is tab delimited and shows up properly in the log but because it's a string i can't use .setValues to write it to the sheet **pt** and i'm not sure how to get the information from the URL in any other way.

i'm sorry for the rudimentary nature of this question but i'm very new to scripting so any help would be appreciated.

Updated Code:

```
function ptDataImport() { 
  var input = "https://reports.acc-q-data.com/clientreports/ecaldwell_201206192722/ecaldwell_2012062.txt";  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(input);  // Get the data from the URL as an object.
  var data = response.getContentText();  // Convet the object to text
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("pt");  // Get the sheet to write the data to  
  var rows = data.split('\n');  // Splits the text into rows
  dataSheet.clear();
  var dataSet = new Array();
  for ( var i in rows){
    dataSet[i] = rows[i].split('\t'); // Split the rows into individual fields and add them to the 2d array
  }
  dataSet.pop(); // Had a blank row at the bottom that was giving me an error when trying to set the range - need to make this conditional somehow
  var numColumns = dataSet[0].length;
  var numRows = dataSet.length;
  var lastRow = dataSet[(numRows -1)];
  dataSheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,numColumns).setValues(dataSet);  // Get a range the size of the data and set the values
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Serge, I think Evan's question was different. Evan is concerned that the split does not take rows into consideration.

The solution to that is to use two splits. First,

```
var rows = data.split('\n');
```

And then

```
for ( var i in rows){
  tmp = rows[i].split('\t'); // Use Serge's method if this doesn't work
  /* Get the range here */
  range.setValues([tmp]); 
}
```

Comment: this worked great and is much simpler than the function from the tutorial mentioned above. i'm still having a problem with the script timing out though (although if i exit the spreadsheet and reopen it all of the data actually has been imorted), is this a problem with my script or just because i'm trying to write nearly 2000 rows to the sheet? i posted my updated script in the original question above.

Comment: To prevent timing out, you can prepare your 2D array for the entire sheet and then use setValues() in one go rather than doing it for every row. This will be much faster

Comment: it took me a bit to get it right but got it working - posted the updated code. thanks a million for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Range.setValues() takes a 2-D array as input.

I'm not sure what you want to do. If all you want to do is write data into a cell, then use this piece of code

```
ptSheet.getActiveRange().setValues([[data]]);
```

If you want to write each of the elements in data to a row in a spreadsheet, then you can use

```
var tmp = data.split(DELIMITER); 
/* Get the correct range here */
range.setValues([tmp]);
```

Notice how you are creating a 2-D array in the first case and in the second case.

Comment: that makes sense. the one problem i am having now is that **data.split("\t")** is not detecting the return that delimits the end of a row. is there something built in for that? i did find a tutorial for [importing from CSV](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section1), would this be a better way?

Comment: i got the tutorial mentioned above to work but because the original file is quite large it is timing out so if .split() can simplify it or if there is another simpler way i would appreciate the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest thing to do is to convert those tabs in something else, commas for example, that's after all where the 'c' of csv comes from... you can then write it wherever you want.

Exemple :
  `commaString = tabString.replace(\t/g,',') ;` should work but I'm not an expert in regEx... if I'm wrong someone will for sure correct it ;-)

Comment: will converting the tabs to commas make it simpler to write it to the google sheet?